# AngularJS app and API on the same domain

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a AngularJS application that I launch from a gulp command line
and run on port `3000`.

In this app, as it's in a development state, I have some http requests like this one :

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/myapi/customers")
.then(function(response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
```

The gulp script minifies, uglifies and syncs changes with the browser.

The `myapi` is a NodeJS / Express simple app that runs with this command :

```
node myapi.js
```

What I want to achieve is giving the relative URL to the api instead of giving the full URL just like this :

```
$http.get("/myapi/customers")
.then(function(response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;});
```

How can I do that ? I could find resources about unifying APIs and AngularJS apps domains.

Regards

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http see "interceptors" . ($httpProvider.interceptors)

Comment: You don't need to give full URL. Relative URLs just work. If the domain that AngularJS app runs on is `localhost:8080`, `/myapi/customers` is equivalent to `localhost:8080/myapi/customers`.

Comment: @dfsq: since you can modify `'request': function(config) { return config; }`, it seems you can change the url before the http real call.

Comment: I think your answer can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware